# Propensity Score Matching with panel data

Tags: r, panel-data, propensity-score-matching

I am trying to use `MatchIt` to perform Propensity Score Matching (PSM) for my panel data. The data is panel data that contains multi-year observations from the same group of companies.

The data is basically describing a list of bond data and the financial data of their issuers, also the bond terms such as issued date, coupon rate, maturity, and bond type of bonds issued by them. For instance:

| Firmnames | Year | ROA | Bond_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAPL US Equity | 2015 | 0.3 | 0 |
| AAPL US Equity | 2015 | 0.3 | 1 |
| AAPL US Equity | 2016 | 0.3 | 0 |
| AAPL US Equity | 2017 | 0.3 | 0 |
| C US Equity | 2015 | 0.3 | 0 |
| C US Equity | 2016 | 0.3 | 0 |
| C US Equity | 2017 | 0.3 | 0 |

......

I've already known how to match the observations by the criteria I want and I use `exact = Year` to make sure I match observations from the same year. The problem now I am facing is that the observations from the same companies will be matched together, this is not what I want. The code I used:

`matchit(Bond_type ~ Year + Amount_Issued + Cpn + Total_Assets_bf + AssetsEquityRatio_bf + Asset_Turnover_bf, data = rdata, method = "nearest", distance = "glm", exact = "Year")`

However, as you can see, in the second raw of my sample, there might be two observations in one year from the same companies due to the nature of my study (the company can issue bonds more than one time a year). The only difference between them is the Bond_type. Therefore, the `MathcIt` function will, of course, treat them as the best control and treatment group and match these two observations together since they have the same ROA and other matching factors in that year.

I have two ways to solve this in my opinion:

1. Remove the observations from the same year and company, however, removing the observations might lead to bias results and ruined the study.
2. Preventing `MatchIt` function match the observations from the same company (or with the same `Frimnames`)

The second approach will be better since it will not lead to bias, however, I don't know if I can do this in `MatchIt` function. Hope someone can give me some advice on this or maybe there's any better solution to this problem, please be so kind to share with me, thanks in advance!

Note: If there's any further information or requirement I should provide, please just inform me. This is my first time raising the question here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with `MatchIt` at the moment (though it's an interesting idea and not hard to implement, so I may add it as a feature).

In the `optmatch` package, which perfroms optimal pair and full matching, there is a constraint that can be added called "anti-exact matching", which sounds exactly like what you want. Units with the same value of the anti-exact matching variable will not be matched with each other. This can be implemented using `optmatch::antiExactMatch()`.

In the `Matching` package, which performs nearest neighbor and genetic matching, the `restrict` argument can be supplied to the matching function to restrict certain matches. You could manually create the restriction matrix by restricting all pairs of observations in the same company and then supply the matrix to `Match()`.

Comment: Hello Noah, please understand your reply means the world to me. I will definitely try the package you've mentioned above.


May I ask the following question, that is, which package will be the most suitable for me if I want to perform nearest- neighbor approach? 


The method I applied in my research requires it, so I am wondering that should I use `optmatch` or `Matching` to do this. I have only limited experience in R programming (2 months) and I will need some more time to learn a new package, so I better choose one that best fits my need.

Comment: Optimal matching and NN matching w/o replacement are essentially the same thing. `optmatch` is easier to use and gives you access to full matching (which is an even better method) but may be slow with large datasets (> 100000 rows). `Matching` is a bit harder to use but has more options for customization and gives access to genetic matching, which is also a great method, and matching with replacement. It will be faster for larger datasets. If you ask questions on here I can help you use them for your purposes.

Comment: Hi Noah. THANK YOU again for answering my detailed questions. I will try `optmatich` since my dataset is way below 100000 rows. If I encounter any further issues I will raise my questions again, and hopefully, get your helpful and detailed answers.

Comment: Glad I was helpful. Feel free to mark this answer as selected so the question isn't lingering. BTW, I decided to add this feature to `MatchIt`, so it should appear in the next release.

Comment: No probs I will do that immediately. May I ask that when will the latest version of  `MatchIt'` will be released? Thanks again for your kindness.